# How do I get my select box on vue jS to show a placeholder / default message?

Tags: html, vue.js, select

I have been searching for a while and no answers appear to help, so apologies if this feels like a duplicate.

I am creating a wedding website, and require an RSVP option. I am using a select box, and would like to set a default placeholder so the user knows what the field is for (I am not using labels so please do not suggest this.

Here is my code:

```
            <select v-model="attending" name="attending" id="attending" placeholder="Please choose" required>
                <option value="" disabled selected>RSVP here</option>
                <option v-for="option in options" v-bind:value="option.id">
                    {{ option.name }}
                </option>
            </select>
            <template v-if="attending === 1">
                <textarea name="message" v-model="message" cols="30" rows="5"
                    placeholder="Please mention any dietary requirements you may have">
                </textarea>
                <p>We would also love for you to have a say on what music plays to get you on the dancefloor. Please
                    feel free to suggest 1 or 2 options below:</p>
                <input type="text" v-model="songone" name="songone" placeholder="Your first song choice">
                <input type="text" v-model="songtwo" name="songtwo" placeholder="Your second song choice">
                <p>Finally, can you please enter the password found on your invitation before submitting:</p>
                <input type="password" v-model="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter password" required>
            </template>


data() {
    return {
        enteredPassword: '',
        errorMessage: '',
        attending: "RSVP",
        options: [
            { id: 1, name: 'I will be there' },
            { id: 2, name: 'Sadly, I am unable to attend' }
        ]
    }
},
```

I thought using the `disabled` or `selected` attr would solve but no luck.

Can someone please show me the really easy way that this will work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to initialize your v-model of `attending` to the value of your placeholder option which you've set as empty string (`""`)

```js
data() {
  return {
    attending: ""
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As [`@yoduh`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6225326/yoduh) Suggested, As we are using `v-model` directive on select to bind the value of selected option. In the same way we can bind the default value by just assigning the `v-model` data value.

```
<option value="RSVP" disabled>RSVP here</option>
```

Live Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    attending: "RSVP",
    options: [
      { id: 1, name: 'I will be there' },
      { id: 2, name: 'Sadly, I am unable to attend' }
    ]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <select v-model="attending" name="attending" id="attending" placeholder="Please choose" required>
    <option value="RSVP" disabled>RSVP here</option>
    <option v-for="option in options" v-bind:value="option.id">
      {{ option.name }}
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
```